# How do I copy PART of an input field to another field?

Tags: jquery, input, copy

I know how to copy an input field to something else.  No prob.  How do I copy part (ie. the month of a date field) to another field.

I want to take a field that is a date range (ie. 7-13-09 to 7-15-09) and copy it to two input fields (ie. the start date and end date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#startDate, #endDate").each( function( i ) {
    $(this).val( $("#dateRange").val().split(" to ")[ i ] )
})
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear about this.  How do I split "06/12/2008,06/19/2008" to two input fields?

Comment: Whao!  Sorry, I got it!  jQuery is really new to me.  Sorry, I just skimmed... :)